# Обработка экшена onClick

Tags: java, android, listener

Допустим, есть кнопка по клику которой вызывается метод.
Как выполнить одноразовый вызов метода, при очень частом клике?

Comment: заведите флаг, который будет определять, можно выполнять метод, или нет. И ставьте его в `true, false`, когда надо

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean isclicked=false;

final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.justButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
        if(!isclicked){
            isclicked=true;
            justMethod();
         }
     }
});

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (null != arrayOfList && arrayOfList.size() != 0) {
        TOTAL_ITMES = Integer.parseInt(arrayOfList.get(0).getId());
        for (Item item : arrayOfList) {
            mainArrayList.add(item);
        }
    }
    setAdapterToListview();
    isclicked=false;
}
```

Ну или же можно скрывать кнопку методом `setEnabled()` при нажатии на кнопку, а после выполнения метода делать ее вновь доступной. Хотя, я думаю, все зависит от задачи.
[Повтор вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314315/android-button-disable-multiple-clicks)